# How to send forgot password request from firebase with email given on database and not w=on authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, forgot-password

I have registered user with mobile id

```
 String id = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID) + "@gmail.com";
```

Now asking user to setup PIN and storing it in database
Let say

```
String Confirmed_Pin = "123456789";
String pass=Confirmed_Pin;
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(id, pass);
```

Now asking user for email and mobile and storing it in realtime database
 Now if user forgots pin how one can send forgot password and change it via email in database Is it possible?

OR how to update this id with mobile

I know this but cannot do via database:

```
mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
```

Comment: Everything will go as you planned but you will receive problem when you try to reset password. Cause user try to reset password won't work because of his email you need to ask email to user while registering with mobile no. if you see you're **id** it holds the device id.

Answer (score 0):

Use this chunk of code. Hopefully it will help.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().sendPasswordResetEmail("user@example.com")
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
            }
        }
    });
```